# how to check the content of a variable on submit

Tags: jquery

I have a form that takes some post code, I'm trying to check the given post code by the user with the pre-defined post-code variable

```
 <form id="post_code">
        <input name="textfield" type="text" id="postcode" size="8" maxlength="8" />
        <input type="image" id="submit_postcode" src="images/B_go.png" alt="Submit Postcode" width="59" height="24" border="0" />
 </form>


var districtPostcodes = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3','B4'];
$("#submit_postcode").submit(function(){
    var userPostcode = $("#postcode").val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/gi,'').toUpperCase();
    $.grep(districtPostcodes , function(val, i){
        if(userPostcode.indexOf(val) === 0){
            alert("Users postcode is part of district: "+val);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: the above code doesn't work. I need to check the value submitted by the user against the var districtPostcodes and alert if its ok, also disable the submit button.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I see two problems with your code.

Firstly, the `if/else` block is missing the terminating `}`.  This was only evident after I applied proper indenting to the code you pasted.

Secondly, `.indexOf` is not cross-browser.  You should use [`$.inArray`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.inArray).

If you're trying to check if the value of `userPostcode` exists in the `districtPostcodes` array, then you would call `$.inArray(userPostcode, districtPostcodes)` and compare the result to `-1`.